# Microsoft teams no longer opening external links

Tags: reactjs, botframework, microsoft-teams

The external links are no longer opened from my tab inside Microsoft Teams desktop app, in the browser version, the links work fine. The tab is written in React. I tried to open the links using the *a* tag:

`<a target='_top' href='https://mywebsite.com'>My Link</a>`

How can I have links in my tab, when I press this in the desktop app nothing is happening, is there another method to open a link in the browser from tab?

Edit:
Works only the links for other tabs or conversation, if I replace *https* with *msteams* in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> to open. I've had the same problem and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

try using target="_blank" instead of target="_top"